# Dynamically generated Input fields from a JS literal template: input values do not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input-field

I have stacked at this problem and I would appreciate any help - it might be something obvious, but for the time being I am unable to see what's wrong.

Some context:

I am adding dynamically a "group" of fields in a form that describe a person. 
These fields can be empty for a whole new entry, or the user can select from a list of existing persons (described as guests), which I present in a div. 
The user can click on each of these guests divs and add a new row of group inputs with the input values already set.

This is where I have the problem. I am able to add the new row of group inputs and the inputs have their value set, but the value isn't displayed inside the input fields.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/joomquery/odgp2wre

Thanks in advance

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    let passengersRows = $('.booking-passenger-entry');
    let passengersRowsI = passengersRows.length;

    $('.add-guest-as-passenger').on('click', function() {
      let passengerData = {};
      console.clear();
      console.log(this);
      passengerData.guestid = $(this).attr('data-guestid');
      passengerData.passengerid = 0;
      passengerData.lastname = $(this).attr('data-lastname');
      passengerData.firstname = $(this).attr('data-firstname');
      passengerData.passportid = $(this).attr('data-passportid');
      passengerData.age = $(this).attr('data-age');
      passengerData.gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');

      addPassenger(passengerData);
    });

    function addPassenger(passenger) {
      passengersRowsI++;
      let i = passengersRowsI;
      let container = $('#passengers-container');
      let genderSelectOptionA = `<option value="0">Unspecified</option>`;
      let genderSelectOptionB = `<option value="1">Male</option>`;
      let genderSelectOptionC = `<option value="2">Female</option>`;
      if (passenger.gender == 'Male') {
        genderSelectOptionB = `<option value="1" selected>Male</option>`;
      } else if (passenger.gender == 'Female') {
        genderSelectOptionC = `<option value="2" selected>Female</option>`;
      }
      console.clear();
      console.log(passenger);
      let passengerTemplate = `
<div class="row-fluid booking-passenger-entry inputform" id="passengers-container-${i}" data-guestid="${passenger.guestid}" data-passengerid="">
  <input type="text" required id="input-name-last-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][name-last]" class="span3 b-guest-i input name-last" placeholder="Last name" val="John" >
  <input type="text" required id="input-name-first-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][name-first]" class="span3 b-guest-i input name-first" placeholder="First name" val="${passenger.firstname}" >
  <input type="text" required id="input-passport-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][passport]" class="span2 b-guest-i input passport" placeholder="Passport ID" val="${passenger.passportid}" >
  <input type="text" required id="input-age-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][age]" class="span1 b-guest-i input age" placeholder="Age" val="${passenger.age}" >
  <select id="input-gender-${i}" required name="passengers[${i}][gender]" class="span2 b-guest-i input gender">
    ${genderSelectOptionA}
    ${genderSelectOptionB}
    ${genderSelectOptionC}
  </select>
  <div class="btn-group span1 pull-right">
   <div id="passenger-delete-${i}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="input-passengerid-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][passengerid]" class="hidden b-guest-i input" val="" >
  <input type="hidden" id="input-guestid-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][guestid]" class="hidden b-guest-i input" val="${passenger.guestid}" >
</div>`;
      $(container).append(passengerTemplate);

    }

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.booking-passenger-entry {
    padding: 0.3125rem 0;
}
.booking-guest {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 0.3125rem !important;
  line-height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="booking-passengers" class="row-fluid req-passengers" style="">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="passengerlist">
      <h3>Dynamic guestlist:</h3>
      <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
        <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
      </div>

      <div id="passengers-container" class="passengers-container" style="border:1px solid #aaa; min-height: 30px; background: #fafafa;">
      </div>

      <div class="guestlist">
        <h3>You may add passengers from your booking's guestlist</h3>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-8" data-guestid="8" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF1" data-lastname="SomeoneL1" data-passportid="XX2255551" data-age="43" data-gender="Male">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX2255551</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">43</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Male</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-12" data-guestid="12" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF2" data-lastname="SomeoneL2" data-passportid="XX0011221" data-age="41" data-gender="Unspecified">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX0011221</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">41</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Unspecified</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just only one change you need to make.

Change, the atrribute name from `val` **to** `value` in your `passengerTemplate` input elements.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    let passengersRows = $('.booking-passenger-entry');
    let passengersRowsI = passengersRows.length;

    $('.add-guest-as-passenger').on('click', function() {
      let passengerData = {};
      console.clear();
      console.log(this);
      passengerData.guestid = $(this).attr('data-guestid');
      passengerData.passengerid = 0;
      passengerData.lastname = $(this).attr('data-lastname');
      passengerData.firstname = $(this).attr('data-firstname');
      passengerData.passportid = $(this).attr('data-passportid');
      passengerData.age = $(this).attr('data-age');
      passengerData.gender = $(this).attr('data-gender');

      addPassenger(passengerData);
    });

    function addPassenger(passenger) {
      passengersRowsI++;
      let i = passengersRowsI;
      let container = $('#passengers-container');
      let genderSelectOptionA = `<option value="0">Unspecified</option>`;
      let genderSelectOptionB = `<option value="1">Male</option>`;
      let genderSelectOptionC = `<option value="2">Female</option>`;
      if (passenger.gender == 'Male') {
        genderSelectOptionB = `<option value="1" selected>Male</option>`;
      } else if (passenger.gender == 'Female') {
        genderSelectOptionC = `<option value="2" selected>Female</option>`;
      }
      console.clear();

      let passengerTemplate = `
   <div class="row-fluid booking-passenger-entry inputform" id="passengers-container-${i}" data-guestid="${passenger.guestid}" data-passengerid="">
    <input type="text" required id="input-name-last-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][name-last]" class="span3 b-guest-i input name-last" placeholder="Last name" value="John" >
    <input type="text" required id="input-name-first-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][name-first]" class="span3 b-guest-i input name-first" placeholder="First name" value="${passenger.firstname}" >
    <input type="text" required id="input-passport-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][passport]" class="span2 b-guest-i input passport" placeholder="Passport ID" value="${passenger.passportid}" >
    <input type="text" required id="input-age-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][age]" class="span1 b-guest-i input age" placeholder="Age" value="${passenger.age}" >
    <select id="input-gender-${i}" required name="passengers[${i}][gender]" class="span2 b-guest-i input gender">
     ${genderSelectOptionA}
     ${genderSelectOptionB}
     ${genderSelectOptionC}
    </select>
    <div class="btn-group span1 pull-right">
     <div id="passenger-delete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="input-passengerid-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][passengerid]" class="hidden b-guest-i input" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" id="input-guestid-${i}" name="passengers[${i}][guestid]" class="hidden b-guest-i input" value="${passenger.guestid}" >

   </div>`;
      $(container).append(passengerTemplate);

    }

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.booking-passenger-entry {
    padding: 0.3125rem 0;
}
.booking-guest {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 0.3125rem !important;
  line-height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="booking-passengers" class="row-fluid req-passengers" style="">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="passengerlist">
      <h3>Dynamic guestlist:</h3>
      <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
        <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
      </div>

      <div id="passengers-container" class="passengers-container" style="border:1px solid #aaa; min-height: 30px; background: #fafafa;">
      </div>

      <div class="guestlist">
        <h3>You may add passengers from your booking's guestlist</h3>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-8" data-guestid="8" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF1" data-lastname="SomeoneL1" data-passportid="XX2255551" data-age="43" data-gender="Male">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX2255551</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">43</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Male</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-12" data-guestid="12" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF2" data-lastname="SomeoneL2" data-passportid="XX0011221" data-age="41" data-gender="Unspecified">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX0011221</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">41</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Unspecified</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** As the `id`'s are same in your code and it is invalid, conside changing the `id` with assigning index like,

```
   id="input-name-last-${i}"

   id="input-name-first-${i}"
```

Comment: oh my god - yes! I knew it should be something silly. We are getting blind sometimes. Thanks for your time and your good observation skills.

Comment: @Sbpro, I also felt that you have done really good job in this but when I find it out, even me too thought the same.. But while coding we our self don't know where we would make these silly mistakes which are unavoidable.. BTW happy coding..

Comment: this inserts duplicate ids in the HTML which is invalid

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I have just edited my answer by assigning individual index to the ```id``` .. I also agreed with your point but OP's main issue is binding the value not working and hence I didn't concentrate on other lines much.. But now I have edited..

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, As OP has the issue of binding only the input values, I made a solution accordingly.. Also now it is updated.. Please make a  constructive comment and let me update the answer then you can downvote if you feel it is not the right one..

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Maniraj answer's may contain this ids error, because he might had copied my first posted code snippet, on which I had also this issue, which I edited on a second pass.

Answer (score 1):

I find in this example, it is easier to simply put the markup you want in for an input group, hide it and then clone that for each instance.  I will leave it to you on how you actually use the data, I also removed all the id's so no duplicate id is inserted.  If you need the id's you can adjust the clone markup to have them.

The benefit of this is you do not have to maintain HTML in code.

```js
(function($) {
    let passengersRows = $('.booking-passenger-entry');
    let passengersRowsI = passengersRows.length;

    $('.add-guest-as-passenger').on('click', function() {
      let passengerData = {};
      passengerData.guestid = $(this).data('guestid');
      passengerData.passengerid = 0;
      passengerData.lastname = $(this).data('lastname');
      passengerData.firstname = $(this).data('firstname');
      passengerData.passportid = $(this).data('passportid');
      passengerData.age = $(this).data('age');
      passengerData.gender = $(this).data('gender');
      addPassenger(passengerData);
    });

    function addPassenger(passenger) {
      let container = $('#passengers-container');
      let inputGroups = container.find('.booking-passenger-entry');
      let clone = container.find('.hidden-input-group').first().clone(true);
      let i = inputGroups.length;
      // might want this>
      // passenger.passengerid = i;
      let gender = clone.find('.input.gender');
      if (passenger.gender == 'Male') {
        gender.val(1);
      } else if (passenger.gender == 'Female') {
        gender.val(2);;
      }

      clone.find('.name-first').val(passenger.firstname);
      clone.find('.name-last').val(passenger.lastname);
      clone.data('guestid', passenger.guestid);
      clone.data('passengerid', passenger.passengerid);
      clone.find('.input.passport').val(passenger.passportid);
      clone.find('.input.age').val(passenger.age);
      clone.removeClass("hidden-input-group");
      container.append(clone);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.booking-passenger-entry {
  padding: 0.3125rem 0;
}

.booking-guest {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 0.3125rem !important;
  line-height: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.hidden-input-group {
  display: none;
}

#passengers-container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="booking-passengers" class="row-fluid req-passengers" style="">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="passengerlist">
      <h3>Dynamic guestlist:</h3>
      <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
        <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
        <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
        <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
      </div>
      <div id="passengers-container" class="passengers-container">
        <div class="row-fluid booking-passenger-entry inputform hidden-input-group" data-guestid="" data-passengerid="">
          <input type="text" required data-name="" class="span3 b-guest-i input name-last " placeholder="Last name" />
          <input type="text" required class="span3 b-guest-i input name-first" placeholder="First name" />
          <input type="text" required class="span2 b-guest-i input passport" placeholder="Passport ID" />
          <input type="text" required class="span1 b-guest-i input age" placeholder="Age" />
          <select required class="span2 b-guest-i input gender">
            <option value="0">Unspecified</option>
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
          </select>
          <div class="btn-group span1 pull-right">
            <div class="passenger-delete btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" class="hidden b-guest-i input" />
          <input type="hidden" class="hidden b-guest-i input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="guestlist">
        <h3>You may add passengers from your booking's guestlist</h3>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest booking-guest-headings">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-last">Last name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h name-first">First name</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i b-guest-h passport">Passport ID</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i b-guest-h age">Age</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i b-guest-h gender">Gender</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-8" data-guestid="8" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF1" data-lastname="SomeoneL1" data-passportid="XX2255551" data-age="43" data-gender="Male">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF1</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX2255551</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">43</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Male</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid booking-guest add-guest-as-passenger" id="booking-guest-12" data-guestid="12" data-passengerid="0" data-firstname="SomeoneF2" data-lastname="SomeoneL2" data-passportid="XX0011221" data-age="41" data-gender="Unspecified">
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-last">SomeoneL2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i name-first">SomeoneF2</span>
          <span class="span3 b-guest-i passport">XX0011221</span>
          <span class="span1 b-guest-i age">41</span>
          <span class="span2 b-guest-i gender">Unspecified</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```